# Understanding how to convert void* and int* in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have written the following code:

```
typedef struct List {
    struct List* next;
    void *value;
} List;

void freeList(List* list, void destroyElement(void*)) {
    while(list != NULL) {
        destroyElement(list->value);
        struct List* n = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(n);
    }
}

struct List* arr2list(void** array, int length, void* cpyElement(void*), void (*destroyElement)(void*)) {
    struct List* head = NULL;
    struct List** tail = &head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        *tail = calloc(1, sizeof(struct List));
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n",i,*(((int*)array)+i));
        if (*tail == NULL) {
            freeList(head, destroyElement);
            return NULL;
        }
        tail[0]->value = cpyElement(array[i]);
        tail = &(tail[0]->next);
    }
    *tail = NULL;
    return head;
}

void printList(List* list, void echoElement(void*)) {
    while (list != NULL) {
        echoElement(list->value);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

void destroyElement(void* el) {
    if (el != NULL) {
        struct List* node = el;
        node->next = NULL;
        free(node);
    }
}

void* cpyElement(void* el) {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    *p = *(int *) el;
    return p;
}

void echoElement(void* el) {
    if (el != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", *(int *) el);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int array_length = argc - 1;
    int* array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(*array) * array_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
        *(array + i) = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    }
    struct List* root = arr2list((void*) array,array_length,cpyElement, destroyElement);
    printList(root,echoElement);
    freeList(root,destroyElement);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is with `tail[0]->value = cpyElement(array[i]);`. I get a segmentation fault error for this part. If I write it `cpyElement(((int*)array)+i);` it works but I want the function `arr2list` to be generic and not to mention `int`. How can I solve it? I think that I understand it's impossible to convert `void*` to `int*` because it does not know which size to use so is it possible to hear some suggestions on how to approach this issue so it will work? Maybe change the `array` argument?

Comment: 1)stop casting 2) use for-loops.3) void is not  your friend.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`!

Comment: You need to create an array of pointers to ints and then pass that. Yes, it's a lot of malloc calls, but it's necessary.

Comment: @JL2210 what do you mean?

Comment: @vesii See updated answer.

Comment: What exactly is this for? It seems at this point confusing. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of pointers to `int`s and then pass that. Yes, it's a lot of `malloc` calls, but it's necessary (since you're using `void *`).

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct List *root;
    int i, array_length = argc - 1;
    int** array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * array_length);
    for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(*array[i]));
        *array[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    }
    root = arr2list((void **)array,array_length,cpyElement, destroyElement);
    printList(root,echoElement);
    freeList(root,destroyElement);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

This code:

```
void destroyElement(void* el) {
    if (el != NULL) {
        struct List* node = el;
        node->next = NULL;
        free(node);
    }
}
```

will then need to be changed to (in fact, it only worked before due to a platform-specific bug):

```
void destroyElement(void* el) {
    free(el);
}
```

Also, *do not cast the result of `malloc`*. That means *no* `(int *)malloc(...)`. Just use `malloc(...)`, it's safer and doesn't cover up errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `void *` is that while you can freely convert other pointer types to `void *` and back again and get the original pointer back, you need to do that directly -- you can't pass a `void **` where it points at anything other than `void *`'s and expect it to work.

Even worse, in your case, you're passing an array of `int` where an array of `void *` are expected.  You can deal with this by casting yout `int`s to `intptr_t` and thence to `void *` to store in your list -- you'll have to do that double-cast back again to get them out again:

```
void echoElement(void* el) {
       printf("%d ", (int)(intptr_t)el);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int array_length = argc - 1;
    void *array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * array_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
        array[i] = (void *)(intptr_t)atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    }
    struct List* root = arr2list((void*) array,array_length,cpyElement, destroyElement);
    printList(root,echoElement);
```